# Does "as" mean "at the time that"?

Tags: word-usage

Does "as" mean "at the time that " in the following sentences?

"As he finished the speech, the audience burst into applause."
"As I was leaving, the phone rang."

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

Both "as" and "at the time that" are vague about the exact timing of the events. However, they're **both** vague, so you can certainly use the one to explain<sup>†</sup> the other!

> **As** he finished the speech, the audience burst into applause.
>   **At the time that** he finished the speech, the audience burst into applause.

These both mean that the audience applauded *just after* he finished.

> **As** I was leaving, the phone rang.
>   **At the time that** I was leaving, the phone rang.

These both mean that the phone rang *during* the process of leaving.

---

<sup>†</sup> Explain, not replace. Using "at the time that", when "as" would suffice, would be long-winded and even clumsy. It would only be used if you wanted to put extra emphasis on the fact that "these happened at the same time".

Answer (score 0):

### No

In first sentence, `As` means `After`

In second sentence, `As` means `in the process of leaving`

It's meaning depends on the context where it is used.

Comment: But these are both equally captured by "at the time that". Or to put it another way, "as" and "at the time that" are equally vague, and so the latter can replace the former. ...actually, I'm going to go write this up as an answer. I think I can make it clearer with paragraphs.